# xcode avfoundation barcode sanner how to return type of scanned code

Tags: swift, xcode, avfoundation, barcode-scanner

Xcode 12 / Swift 5

AVfoundation

I followed this tutorial for barcode scanner http://www.wepstech.com/bar-qr-code-ios-with-swift-5/

```
func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {     
    if let metadataObject = metadataObjects.first {
        guard let readableObject = metadataObject as? AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject else { return }
        guard let stringValue = readableObject.stringValue else { return }
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))
        found(code: stringValue)
        captureSession.stopRunning()
        parent.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
    }
}
```

It returns the scanned value,

but how to get the barcode TYPE ; to know if it scanned qrcode, code128...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can switch your `metadataObject`'s `type` property and check which one you've got:

```
switch metadataObject.type {
case .qr:
      print("qrcode")
 case .code128:
      print("code128")
 default:
      print("other type")
}
```

Comment: thanks ;) in my case I needed to pass it as a string in a function Xcode proposed me this metadataObject.type.rawValue and when I `print(metadataObject.type.rawValue)` In the console, I see org.iso.qrcode... or org.iso.DataMatrix...